# Comodo certificate apparently recognized in IE but not FF/Seamonkey/

Tags: firefox, certificate, ssl, ca

I am trying to get a Comodo certificate recognized on a webserver written in Python using ssl. When I visit in IE8, the certificate is recognized without difficulty. But when I visit with Firefox 3.0.11/Ubuntu, it says the CA is invalid.

Should Firefox recognize Comodo certificates without giving an invalid CA warning? What can I do to get a certificate recognized? I am presently using a 90-day free trial.

What additional details should I give?

ATdhvaannkcse,
Jonathan

Comment: P.S. Both FF/Ubuntu and FF/XP report Comodo among the (default) trusted CA's, but neither of them accepts the Comodo certificate.

Comment: You can get a free certificate from a CA trusted by both Mozilla and Microsoft at http://startssl.com .  They offer the compelling advantage of only charging you for the work they do validating your identity, instead of charging you per certificate - so you can get as many 2-year certificates as you like for less than $50.  Take a look.

Comment: Thanks! That's a deal worth knowing about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked my system administrator for whatever input he might have, and not that long after, he wrote:

--BEGIN QUOTATION--

Based on the following links I think Mozilla might be upset with Comodo.  I wonder if that is why they don't trust the CA.  Would they even trust a non-free cert we got from Comodo?

http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/blog/2008-12-24/how-to-disable-the-comodo-root-certificate-in-firefox/
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.crypto/browse_thread/thread/9c0cc829204487bf?pli=1
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=470897

--END QUOTATION--

I'm looking into GoDaddy or other options.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are based on trust. Certificate authorities issue certificates and sign them using their root certificates. Browsers come installed with a collection of trusted root certificates from certificate authorities like VeriSign.

It may be that your certificate is from a certificate authority signed by a root certificate that only IE8 trusts and not your particular version of Firefix. You can inspect the certificate to see how it is signed.

In fact, if you didn't purchase your certificate from a certificate authority you may instead have setup things so your certificate is trusted by Windows. IE8 uses Windows for trust, but I believe that Firefox doesn't rely on Windows. Particularily on Ubuntu.

Comment: Correct, Firefox does not use the Windows root store.  You must use the Firefox control panel to add a new root.  My guess is that Comodo's "demo" root isn't trusted by Firefox, although you might have more luck with the 20$ GoDaddy certificate, which is trusted by everyone out of the box.

Comment: 'My guess is that Comodo's "demo" root isn't trusted by Firefox...' Hmm, I'll investigate. (Thanks.) ssl.com/m-12-comodo.aspx only lists one CA for all the Comodo options it lists, and Firefox lists Comodo as a CA. But there may be hidden intricacies; thanks to both of you!